# Google Play console shows Production status as Inactive even i rolled out application with 100%

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have fully (100%) rolled out the android application in production and it is almost a week but unable to download the app (I can only download as internal tester) and not available for everybody. Google play console shows these two status for this app.

```
- Production
    Inactive
- Available on Google Play 
  Full rollout
```

Google Console Show Inactive Status
[image]

Status on Dashboard
[image]

I don't know what is the reason, it is showing status as inactive but says available on Google play. It even shows inactive for Closed and Open Testing too. Only internal testing is active.

Do I still need to wait for Google approval or any setting which is preventing this app further approval. If you see already 8 days passed with first version prod rollout.

Production Dashboard
[image]

Apps current status is published too.

Question : Why it is not yet available on Google Play store?

That's how I see my app in Google Play (Pre-register, because i enabled it)[Current view in Play Store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtFw8.png)

Comment: Click on "View on google play". Or you can try search app by name and than click on new option.

Comment: Hi Sahil, i do see app in Google Play Store. But it shows Coming Soon and option of Pre-register. But this is not available to install.

Comment: Added image in Question, how i see as of now. https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtFw8.png

Comment: In first image, I see your internal testing is active. I don't know much about it but You can try .First click on production on left side than on right side you will see create a new release option click on it.

Comment: I have already rolled out for production.

Answer (score 42):

Go to Advanced settings in google play console.

Check App availabilty is published if not make it published. Then status will become active.

Comment: Where is "Advanced settings"?

Comment: select the app then Setup > Advanced Settings > App Availability

Comment: Thank you, it's actually solved the problem. For some reason when I did transfer the app between account it became unpublished by default

Comment: This also resolved my issue. I inherited several apps and it appears some of them were unpublished in the past and no one knows why.

Answer (score 11):

From the Sidebar Menu:

Setup > Advanced Settings > App Availability

Select Published

Then Save changes

Answer (score 7):

Please check your Countries/Region.
Make sure you selected atleast 1.

Comment: More concretely, for production most likely you will want to check all possible countries where the item is available. And for Pre-registration most likely you will want to disable all countries because you just released in production. Also make sure that unnecessary testings (Internal, Closed, Open) are paused.

Comment: Yep, I selected all countries for my release track & only selected one for the pre-registration, since I can't get rid of that pre-registration track.

Answer (score 2):

This message is also show, If you  forget to full-roll-out, to check go to "Production" below version code of your app, If it show "Draft - inactive" then click "edit release" and roll out once again..

Answer (score -2):

I dont know , this was the reason or not.

Step-1 : I just updated country of availability to unavailable for all country and then saved it.
Step-2: After couple of minutes i marked available to all country.
Step-3: No action, after 30 minutes. Status in production changed from Inactive to active.
Step-4: ll. After couple of hours app is available for download in app store as well. (I need to clear cache and data for Play store app) Before searching the app.

Thanks